Arbitrary functions on compact sets
I have some trouble understanding the statement of the following Proposition:
Proposition:
Let $K$ be a compact set, $f$ an arbitrary real-valued function defined on $K$. Then there exists $x_0 \in K$ such that for every $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_{\epsilon}$ of $x_0$
$(*) \sup f(V_{\epsilon } \cap K)=\sup f(K) $.
My thoughts:
As already stated I have some trouble understanding the meaning of this Proposition.
At first I thought it might be somewhat related to the extreme-value theorem for compact sets, but here continuity of $f$ is not needed.
Regarding $(*)$:
Ignoring the supremum, on the Left-Hand Side we have the Image of f from some neighborhood of $x_0$ (in $K$). On the Right-Hand Side we have the Image of $f$. If we consider the supremum of those sets, it would mean that the supremum of $f$ on the whole set $K$ is attained in some small neighborhood in $K$.
But isn't that wrong?
Consider the following example:
$f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        x & \text{if } x \in [0,1)\\
        0 & \text{if } x=1
    \end{cases}$.
$f$ is not continuous, $sup f([0,1])=1$ but $f$ does not attain its supremum on any $x$ in $[0,1]$.

Because of that it seems that I did not understand the statement of the proposition. Could maybe someone explain the meaning of this Proposition to me?

In your example, take $x_0=1$. Then on every neighborhood of $x_0$, the supremum of $f$ is $1$. .

In that statement, $f$ is not required not to attain its supremum.  My objection is: we have to allow supremum to be $+\infty$, so I think that should be stated in the proposition.

You mentioned “$\epsilon$-neighborhood”. Is the set $K$ a metric space or simply a topological space?

Since $f$ is real-valued, I assume this means $f(x)\neq \infty$ for any $x \in K$. Also, I assume $K$ is a compact set in a metric space $(X,d)$ so that sequentially compact and compact are equivalent.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
Case 1 Suppose $\sup f(K)=A <\infty$. If there is $x_0 \in K$ so that $f(x_0)=A$, then we are done. Otherwise, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we may find $x_n \in K$ so that $A-\frac{1}{n}<f(x_n) \leq A$.
Since $K$ is compact, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{x_{n_j}\}$ that converges to $x_0 \in K$. So there is $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $d(x_0,x_{n_j})<\epsilon$ whenever $j \geq N_1$.
Let $\gamma>0$ be given. By the Archimedean property, we may $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $N_2\gamma>1$. When $j \geq N_2$, we have $n_j \geq n_{N_2} \geq N_2$. So $A-\gamma<f(x_{n_j}) \leq A$ whenever $j \geq N_2$.
Take $N=\max\{N_1, N_2\}$. Then $x_{n_N} \in V_{\epsilon} \cap K$ and $A-\gamma <f(x_{n_N})\leq A$. Since $f(V_{\epsilon } \cap K )\subseteq f(K)$, we know $A$ is an upper bound for $f(V_{\epsilon } \cap K)$. So $\sup f(V_{\epsilon } \cap K)=A$.
Case 2
Suppose $\sup f(K)=\infty$. So $f$ is not bounded above on $K$. This means there is $x_1 \in K$ so that $f(x_1)>1$. Furthermore, there is $x_2 \in K$ so that $f(x_2)>2$. And for each positive integer $n > 2$ we may find $x_n$ so that $f(x_n)>n$. Since $K$ is compact, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{x_{n_j}\}$ that converges to $x_0 \in K$. So there is $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $d(x_0,x_{n_j})<\epsilon$ whenever $j \geq N_1$.
Let $B>0$ be given. By the Archimedean property, we may find $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $N_2>B$. So $f(x_{n_j})>B$ whenever $j \geq N_2$.
Take $N=\max\{N_1, N_2\}$. Then $x_{n_N} \in V_{\epsilon} \cap K$ and $f(x_{n_N})>B$. Thus $\sup f(V_{\epsilon } \cap K)=\infty$.
